# Rules for the game "Chainstore"

Tags: chain-store

There is an old box in our storeroom containing the game Chainstore.  My brother and I bought the game when we were kids (ages ago).  Now my children wants to play it, but the rules are missing.  I've tried to figure it out, but that's not the way to go.

Anybody have a copy of the rules of Chainstore?  It looks like Monopoly-based game.

Comment: Did you ever obtain a copy of the rules. We also obtained the boardgame and the instructions are missing.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

[Dave Elder](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/user/newboy1721) has a copy of Chainstore for trade listed at boardgamegeek.

You could try contacting him via GeekMail there.